# How to set apache Document root on ntfs partition?

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd, php, ntfs

I'm running Arch Linux and installed apache, php and mysql (not mariadb) there. Arch root partition have limited size, because I set big partition on ntfs filesystem for shared files between OS (I'm dual booting with windows). So, I want to move apache's document root to that ntfs partition.

The problem is, `php` files that stored in ntfs partition won't show anything. Even `ini_set('display_errors')` can't help. The only hints is javacript console that said `internal server error`.

I mounted NTFS partition automatically when booting with fstab like this:

```
UUID=3AD4628C7D357A55 /media/data ntfs-3g defaults,uid=1000,gid=100,umask=022,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
```

and `index.php` file permission is `-rwxr-xr-x` with my user as it's owner. If I remve `index.php`, `localhost` showing directory list just fine (i turn Indexes on).

So, how can I do this?

**UPDATE**

The error log says:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/media/data/Projects/www/html/test.php'
 (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://localhost/
```

Comment: Can you execute other programs if you try running them directly?

Comment: Yes I can. No problem for executing program from ntfs partition directly. If you mean via terminal too.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for the info.

Comment: What can you find in apache's error log when the error occurs?

Comment: Edited. Added the error log.

Comment: Does the file `/media/data/Projects/www/html/test.php` exist with the right permissions?

Comment: Yes. The permissions is `755` or `rwxr-xr-x`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to make the apache document root a local directory on the same server that apache is running on. Then, if you must get content over a mount, use symlinks from within the doc root.

The only way I have actually used this kind of setup is pulling static content from over the mount. If you are trying to reach across the mount, execute php on the server that is remotely mounted, and get a response back through your local apache... good luck. If that is what you are doing, then I think you need to re-think your solution. I could be wrong.